# How can I handle incoming Intents from external applications in Flutter with android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Tags: android-manifest, flutter

In the Flutter documentation [here](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-intent-in-flutter) under 
**How do I handle incoming Intents from external applications in Flutter**
the Manifest shows `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and the shared text is transfered in flutter `void initState()` with the `getSharedText();` method in a state variable.

Anyhow, everytime I share text to the app a new instance of the app is created.
So I changed the manifest to the Manifest to `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` (or singleTask).

In this case `void initState()` is only called once and can not be used to call `getSharedText();` anymore. I tried to use `AppLifecycleState.resumed` to call `getSharedText();` there but the data is always null. I wish flutter would have example projects for this. I could not find them. Any hints?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question could be the [uni_links package](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links).

You simply set up a listener to the incoming App/Deep links and call whatever methods you need :)

I do this like that:

```dart
_linkStream = getUriLinksStream().listen((uri) {
  if (uri.host == 'redirect' && uri.queryParameters.containsKey('code')) { // Checking the url

    // Do my stuff here

    _linkStream.cancel();
  }
});
```

The `_linkStream` is a `StreamSubscription<Uri>` property in my class. Also, don't forget to `dispose()` the subscription in your `dispose()` method!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the intent in `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` (or singleTask) with this plugin [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent).

There it works with this method for texts:

```dart
ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((String value) {
  setState(() {
    _sharedText = value;
  });
}, onError: (err) {
  print("getLinkStream error: $err");
});
```

Currently (September 24th) the plugin also supports pictures and videos.

However, I didn't delve any further into the plugin, so I can't say how to implement it directly with Java/Kotlin.